# Empty fields as "0" by default

Tags: javascript

**Input fields**:

```
<input name="qty1" id ="qty1" type="text" onblur="sum()"/>
<input name="qty2" id ="qty2" type="text" onblur="sum()"/>
<input name="qty3" id ="qty3" type="text" onblur="sum()"/>
<input name="qty4" id ="qty4" type="text" onblur="sum()"/>
<input name="total" id ="total" type="text"/>
```

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sum(){
      //grab the values
      qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value;
      qty2 = document.getElementById('qty2').value;
      qty3 = document.getElementById('qty3').value;
      qty4 = document.getElementById('qty4').value;
      document.getElementById('total').value = parseFloat(qty1) + parseFloat(qty2) + parseFloat(qty3) + parseFloat(qty4);
  }
  </script>
```

Code displays 4 fields where user can insert a number, the 5th field recalculates the total e.g.: 1st field (qty1): **1**, 2nd field (qty2): **2**, 3rd field (qty3): **3**, 4th field (qty4): **4**, 5th field (total): **10** (1+2+3+4 = 10).

I would like to make this code more user friendly, so the script automatically treats **empty fields** as **0**. Currenly if user leave field empty, the total shows "NaN"

Any advise?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: `if ( isNaN(v) ) v = 0;`

Comment: Try qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value || 0; for 1 - 4

Comment: @u_mulder: `isNaN('')` is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sum(){
  //grab the values
  qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value || 0;
  qty2 = document.getElementById('qty2').value || 0;
  qty3 = document.getElementById('qty3').value || 0;
  qty4 = document.getElementById('qty4').value || 0;
  document.getElementById('total').value = parseFloat(qty1) + parseFloat(qty2) + parseFloat(qty3) + parseFloat(qty4);
}
```

Comment: @Musa the questions is about handling empty fields. letters are not mentioned in the scenario :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning, op might come back later and ask how to prevent NaN if the user some other type of data.

Comment: @musa, do a test to see if the input is a number and treat everthing else as zero. number test: if ( /\d+/.test(document.getElementById('qty1').value) )

Answer (score 3):

use isNaN function to determine the value if value exist and is numeric or not and assign default value if it does not.

```
if(!isNan(qty4)){
    qty=0;
}
```

Comment: `isNaN('')` is `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, if you didn't use `parseFloat`, then you wouldn't get `NaN` in the first place. `parseFloat('')` returns `NaN`.

You should still convert the strings to numbers though, but instead of `parseFloat`, use [the unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29). `+''` returns `0`, because the mathematical value of an empty string is `0`:

```
function sum(){
  //grab the values
  var qty1 = +document.getElementById('qty1').value;
  var qty2 = +document.getElementById('qty2').value;
  var qty3 = +document.getElementById('qty3').value;
  var qty4 = +document.getElementById('qty4').value;
  document.getElementById('total').value = qty1 + qty2 + qty3 + qty4;
}
```

Now you only get `NaN` if the the user provides a value that cannot be converted to a number, such as `abc`. To fix that, you can indeed use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Here is fixed and more concise version of your code, making use of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function sum(){
  document.getElementById('total').value = 
    [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(total, id) {
       var v = +document.getElementById('qty'+id).value;
       return total + isNan(v) ? 0 : v; 
    }, 0);
}
```